# How to see what exact events are bound to DOM elements?

Tags: javascript, jquery, events

I feel I want to do this often but can't because I don't have access to the actual events.

For example (and this is just an example as I **can** just look at the API instead) I was trying to see how stackoverflow's image uploader works, but when I call `$($0).data('events)` (or `$('form[action="/upload/image"] :submit').data('events')` ) I get `undefined`. Is there any other way to look at the actual functions of certain events?

If so, is there also a way to set breakpoints on those events?

EDIT:

Using `Visual Event` this is what I see

[image]

Comment: You can set breakpoints for events in your debugger. E.g. in Dragonfly you can set event-breakpoints in the tab "breakpoints" next to "state" (in the "scripts" view).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Personally, I use a mix of Firebug and [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).

**EDIT:** The event highlights don't always line up perfectly due to positioning.

I managed to find the image submit function here:
[image: Visual Event example]

Comment: Where did you find that? I see **a** submit event but when I mouseover it I only see a `0` , in fact most of the events just show a `0`

Comment: @qwertymk It's the highlighted area that actually spans the width of the pop-up; you can just about see it in the image above the function definition.

Comment: It works for some events but the submit event and a couple of others just shows a `0`

Comment: Sorry, I'm out of ideas - just one of those times that "well, it works for me" I guess!

Comment: Check it's the latest version is all I can suggest (looks different to my image)

Comment: Well I just added the bookmarklet five minutes ago so I hope it is. I tried it on both Chrome and FF

Answer (score 0):

In recent versions of jQuery (from 1.7 onwards) they changes the internal structure of the way events are stored s[ee this blog post](http://blog.jquery.com/2011/11/08/building-a-slimmer-jquery/).

You can still get at the events but it's done a bit *differently*:

```
var events = jQuery._data(element, 'events');
```

Comment: That's because it's not on the `:submit` element, the handler is on the form.