# How can I tell what events are bound to a DOM element?

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, event-listener, web-inspector

When using the Wordpress visual editor, if you have a `[gallery]` shortcode, in visual mode it is presented with a placeholder.

Clicking the placeholder will overlay two icons - edit gallery and remove gallery.

I'm trying to figure out what function fires when 'edit gallery' is clicked.

The button is an image, with the dom id `wp_editgallery`, and this is how it looks:

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

My instincts are to inspect the element using Chrome's web inspector:

[image]

After finding the element, I check out the properties panel and look for events, but the results are somewhat cryptic:

[image: screenshot-with-shadow.png]

So far I've tried the above method, and also:

```
var events = jQuery._data('#wp_editgallery', 'events');
```

As was recommended in [How to see what exact events are bound to DOM elements?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10182993/how-to-see-what-exact-events-are-bound-to-dom-elements) I also tried using `Visual Event` as was mentioned in that post - both without success.

Is there an easier way of find out what javascript function is tied to an DOM element's event listener?

Answer (score -1):

check out [Visual Event](http://www.sprymedia.co.uk/article/Visual+Event).  Works awesome with Chrome!  Lets you view and run the events attached to DOM elements.  Has been a life saver!

Comment: Not sure if you saw that I mentioned Visual Event in the question... Basically it did not prevent the popup modal from popping up, which covered up Visual Event. Additionally there were so many things on the page that Visual Event caused that tab to lock up. Even before it locked up I couldn't figure out what function anything was tied to.